# How do I find a certain application on the user's PC and transfer data to it? (VB)

Tags: vb.net, parameters, windows-8.1, desktop

I'm developing an app on the Windows desktop so Win7 users have the app, but for Win8 users I'm also developing a Metro app.

My problems are,

1. if a user opens a file (e.g. "Blue.xyz"), I want an app to come up that asks which environment to open it in, but first it has to find all the apps that can open the file and display them.
2. Then I need to pass the data as a parameter to the app Chosen.
3. In the .NET framework ***4.5.1***, I can't find the System.GetEnvironmentVariable command so I can create a common location for both environments to access. These are my options:

   [image]

Comment for clarification.

Comment: Just register both applications as potential handlers for `.xyz` files and let Windows do the prompting.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my first and second questions. Any ideas about the third?

Comment: @Joe: Why can't you use 4.5?

Comment: Actually, it's there, just not showing on MSDN. See the answer I added (could not paste the proof image otherwise).

Comment: I can use 4.5 for the desktop app, but the metro app is for Windows 8.1. Sorry I didn't say that earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your 3rd question, the function is there, just now showing on MSDN page:

[image]

Comment: See the post edit. It doesn't work with VS 2013 Ultimate and .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: @Joe: It may not be available for metro, too risky to be allowed. I used a console app, as you can see above.

Answer (score 1):

After having an inspiration, I found some code that can get pretty close to what I want.

```
Dim filepicker As New Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
CommonFolder = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
```

I should just be able to tack this on the end after that:

```
CommonFolder.Replace("\Documents","")
```

and it should give me "C:\Users\someuser" and then I can add "\MyAppStorage"

Thanks for all the help though! This code isn't very clean, so feel free to edit and make it better!